# Javascript variable in angular controller

Tags: angularjs

How Can i access my javascript variable in my angular controller. 
my javascript is

```
function getRecaptchResponse(){
        var challengeVal = Recaptcha.get_challenge();
        var reponseVal = Recaptcha.get_response();
    //alert("reponseVal is " + reponseVal + "challengeVal  is" + challengeVal );
     $.ajax({
        url: "html/views/my.jsp",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
        challengeVal  : challengeVal,
        reponseVal: reponseVal
              },
        success: function(data){
            console.log("success in Recaptcha " + data);                    
            if (data == "valid"){
                $('#recaptchsStatus').val("valid");                                     
                        }   
            else{                                        
                                    $('#recaptchsStatus').val("invalid");
                Recaptcha.reload();
                }   
             },
            error:function(){
                    console.log("error occured in Recaptcha");
                       }
                       });
                }
```

I have also added one hidden html element in my page

```
  <input type="hidden"  id="recaptchsStatus"  ng-model="reStatus"/>
```

my controller is as follows.

```
 angular.module('myWebApp').controller('signInController',function ($scope){
   console.log(" status  is " + $scope.reStatus);   
  });
```

But I am getting status is undefined error. 
Please point me in right direction to resolve this issue.

Comment: seems like there is not all of your code.

Comment: You are not getting the updated value because your are setting `#recaptchsStatus` outside of angularjs.  How is `getRecaptchResponse` triggered?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are not doing your application the Angular-way. When doing an AngularJS application, all your Javascript code should be contained by AngularJS inside a module, a controller, a service or a directive.

In your example, you should put your AJAX call inside your controller, and use `$http.post`. It will check your $scope at the end of your callback. Inside this callback, you'll be able to inject its result inside your $scope, and access it inside your view.

To learn more, watch this [lesson](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-http) by EggHead showing how to use $http with its best practices.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. My problem was that I can not call my AJAX call in my controller because  challengeVal and reponseVal values are available only in javascript and not in controller.

Comment: AJAX call should really be contained in a service, or a factory. This in turn should be injected into a controller. If we are talking about correct angular-way approach.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out way to do this. I am using $window approach to access java script variable in my controller.